# What does "this rather old photo up" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, spoken-english

I had participated in the lecture hosted by Tim Brown at TEDGlobal 2009.

The title is "Designers- think big!".

He said something like

> "I'd like to talk a little bit morning about what happens if we move from design to design thinking. **Now this rather old photo up** there is actually the first project I was ever hired to do, something like 25 years ago....".

I am not sure what "**Now this rather old photo up**" means.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sentence is drawing your attention to a specific thing

> this rather old photo

in  a specific place

> up there

meaning the high place he is indicating.

Probably he means on a display screen.

Comment: I've up-voted, because this gets to the heart of it, but what about the "now" bit? It seems like that could cause some confusion as well.

Comment: @ColleenV - I'm assuming there is a comma missing: *Now, this rather old photo up there*... If that hunch is correct, then _now_ might just be a "filler word" that adds no real meaning to the sentence. I like this definition of _now_ (from Macmillan): used when you want to get people’s attention or to show that you are going to talk about something new.

Answer (score 0):

You have missed out part of the relevant phrase: *up there*.  This shows you where the photo is: up on the slide he is showing.  This is a common phrase for talking about something in a slide show. The rest of the text tells you that the photo is rather old.